# How to gauge If i will be rolled out an offer letter? Or what to do next?

Tags: job-search, salary, job-offer, negotiation

Went through the entire Hiring process for a company , where I :

1. Applied on a Job portal
2. Received a quick reply within two days
3. Cleared two rounds of Interview one with the Hiring Manager other with the AVP of that Department itself
4. Got a reply back from the HR team within two days or so discussing in depth as to why I am willing to shift or change again (It would be my 4th Company under 3 yrs ) , explained all the details
5. HR asked for my Salary details & Offer Letter etc. in a Mail stating that the Team has really liked my profile & congratulations !!  (Though it seemed to be that the Salary demands might be an issue )

Now after a day of sharing the Salary details she replied that " Sure  I will update you after I discuss with my Team" (They want me to join early within a month and they will have to Buy me out for a Month also)

Do you think I can still bag the offer or should i Wait or have my chances of landing an offer vanished. ?

Comment: What does it matter what we think? It matters what your would be employer thinks, and we have no way to know that...

Comment: Roll dice. If it's 6-6 or 6-5, you get an offer. If it's it's 2-2 or 4-4, you don't. Any other outcome, roll again ;)

Comment: `HR asked for my Salary details & Offer Letter etc`..you mean from the previous employment, right?

Comment: You stop sending resumes three days after you're sitting in your new desk

Answer (score 3):

> Do you think I can still bag the offer

It's possible.  It sounds like you did your part.

> or should i Wait

For what?  **Assume the worst, hope for the best.**  Keep looking, keep applying elsewhere until you've actually landed a job.  There is no reason for you to pause your job search while waiting for these folk.  They're looking at other candidates, you may as well be looking at other opportunities.

> or have my chances of landing an offer vanished. ?

We don't know your chances and neither do you.  Go ahead and get your hopes up, but at the same time keep looking.

If you're very lucky you might have two job offers to consider.

[Martin Bonner](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/47492/martin-bonner) made a great point in a comment:

> if you do get another offer before these folk have offered, it is entirely acceptable to get in contact to say "I have been made another offer, but I am very interested in working for you. Do you know when you will be able to reach a decision on my application?"

Comment: "There is no reason for you to pause your job search while waiting for these folk." - Probably worth saying that if you do get another offer before these folk have offered, it is entirely acceptable to get in contact to say "I have been made another offer, but I am very interested in working for you.  Do you know when you will be able to reach a decision on my application?"

Answer (score 0):

> *Do you think I can still bag the offer or should i Wait or have my chances of landing an offer vanished. ?*

Well, you did *your* part. Appeared for the interview(s), created a positive impression for yourself and reverted with all the information asked. Now, it's up to the company and company policies to take the final call. There is nothing more at this moment you can do, except to wait for hearing back from them.

Wait for a sensible amount of time for their response. So far, they have been quick enough to respond, and from your description, it appears that the requirement is immediate - so they should be getting back to you pretty soon(-ish, I'd say 2-3 working days would be a fair assumption).

After that, you can have a follow up with them, either with the offer or with a negotiation proposal on salary. Until then, don't think about it, just carry on.

Comment: Sometimes getting the official approval can take weeks. Lots of politics and fund allocations can be going on behind the scenes. The best advice is to keep looking but check in every so often with the company. Heck, for my current job it took months because of politics. Thankfully an exception, but the final steps can be the ones that take the most time so be patient. But never stop looking if looking is what one has been doing.

Comment: @Jonast92 I do not advise against that in any ways, just want to make it clear that we cannot _predict_ the final outcome, we need to wait and watch. Also, I mentioned the need of follow up after 2-3 days (entire second paragraph is dedicated to it)...so not really sure what you're trying to point out in your comment.

Comment: It's more of an extension to yours to tell OP that this part of the process can take the longest. It's not really a criticism on your answer.

Comment: @Jonast92 Ah OK, I thought you are trying to point me to mention the follow up part (which I already did). Thanks for the explanation, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you think I can still bag the offer or should i Wait or have my chances of landing an offer vanished

**It doesn't matter**.

Pretend like it's vanished. Keep looking for a job, keep scheduling interviews, keep chasing leads. You have a *we'll think about it*, you don't have an offer.

After a week has passed you can send them an email to ask about the status. But for now you don't have an offer. Fretting about it is **not a good use of your time**.